# How to use variable in prefix routes?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

With api platform 3.1, I'm trying to use a variable in my prefix declaration :

```
# config/routes/api_platform.yaml

api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /{var}/api
```

But since this {var} is not in the operations metada and it's not a field of my entities I got a message like :
`Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type *path to my entity*`
for all operations of any entities.

FYI: this var is used as a 'database selector'

So I'm looking for ideas to handle this.
My goal would be to have this var in the identifiers when generating the route : [here](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/main/src/Symfony/Routing/IriConverter.php#L187)
I tried to modify the iriConverter or the AbstractItemNormalizer but without success.

My last hope would be to override symfony Router but it seems to be a "big thing" for this.

Comment: You would perform this inside your controller. The API Platform has [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/) on this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Bossman but I'm not sure to understand what you mean. This {var} is not a real identifier (the field is not a part of the entity) and I'm not sure I can access to the request form the controller.

Comment: Yes the var can be anything, it will match in your route and you can access the request in your controllers. You should have a read on how Symfony [routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) works.

Comment: Ok my bad, I though a API Platform controller would be diffrent from a Symfony controller. The idea should work indeed. My problem remain since I need this for every entities ( and if I can avoid changing all of them it can be nice ^^'). 
I think I found a solution, I will post it in the awnser. Thanks @Bossman

Comment: You can add route annotations to the actual class that will be shared with all methods (controllers) within that class, mentioned in the routing docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-groups-and-prefixes).

Answer (score 0):

Since I need to have this {var} in all my entities' routes, one solution is to decorate the "router.default" :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Decorator;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\AsDecorator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\MapDecorated;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\WarmableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

#[AsDecorator(decorates: 'router.default')]
class DecoratorRouter implements RouterInterface, WarmableInterface
{
    public function __construct(#[MapDecorated] private Router $originalRouter, private RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
    }

    public function generate(string $name, array $parameters = [], int $referenceType = self::ABSOLUTE_PATH): string
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        if ($request && $request->attributes->has('var')) {
            $parameters['var'] = $request->attributes->get('var');
        }

        return $this->originalRouter->generate($name, $parameters, $referenceType);
    }

    public function getRouteCollection()
    {
        return $this->originalRouter->getRouteCollection();
    }

    public function match(string $pathinfo): array
    {
        return $this->originalRouter->match($pathinfo);
    }

    public function setContext(RequestContext $context)
    {
        return $this->originalRouter->setContext($context);
    }

    public function getContext(): RequestContext
    {
        return $this->originalRouter->getContext();
    }

    public function warmUp(string $cacheDir)
    {
        return $this->originalRouter->warmUp($cacheDir);
    }
}
```